# Where is the 'about' link for Sports.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, tour, top-bar

I have 6 accounts in Stack Exchange, I can see the *about* page link in all sites, but not in Sports.SE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any reputation limit to show the *about* page link in the top menu bar?

Comment: It's only shown when your rep is below 10k on graduated sites and 2k on Beta sites.

Comment: @Bart 1607<2000

Comment: Will you just stop it with your facts and correctness @ShaWizDowArd. Very annoying. :) Yep, swapped sports and SO reputation when I made the comment. D'oh.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It could be the numbers have been adjusted. It does look like a too-high-rep issue. Perhaps the cut-off for beta sites is now 1.5k?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what I thought as well, can't find any proof though. Think better tag this as a bug in the meanwhile?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this **as a low rep user**. I signed up at Sports.SE (I did not yet have an account there), and I see the About link in the title bar. I think *you* don't see it because you have more than 1500 points of reputation on a beta site.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No, I can see the about link just fine. This is almost certainly a too-high-reputation issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, do you have any beta account with 1.5k reputations?

Comment: @Azik: If I did I'd already have tested that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, are you sure that this is a high rep score issue? Is this discussed or documented anywhere?

Comment: @Azik: I am 99% sure, based on your scores and what I know from experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The About page link will only be shown to the user when his/her reputation is less than 1500 on beta sites.

Today, I've passed 1500 reputations on Islam.SE beta site and I can't see the about page link.

[image]

Comment: I have less than 6k on [so] but I don't see the about page link.

Comment: then it will be 3 to 5k for graduated sites, I answered from the [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190873/where-is-the-about-link-for-sports-se/193492?noredirect=1#comment592696_190873) of @Bart

Comment: @Azik - Any reference for 3K on graduated sites?

Comment: @hims056, it might be 3 to 5k as Antony's statement, I guess it as 3k(double of 1.5)  ;)

Comment: @hims056, as the question is about beta site, the answer is correct.

Comment: @Azik - Can you see "about" on SO?

Comment: @hims056, see the question, I can.